# Is there any way to launch a particular Activity from Espresso Recorder?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I am using Espresso for my UI Testing. In Espresso, I can test any particular activity I want without having to go from the first activity with the following rule.

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule(HomeActivity.class);
```

Note: Here `HomeActivity` comes after `LoginActivity`.

But when I am using [Espresso recorder](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/test-recorder), it always seems to begin the test from `LoginActivity`.I need to launch `HomeActivity` directly. So is there any option in Android Studio to launch a particular activity with Espresso Recorder.

Answer (score 6):

I just edit the manifest and set the activity I want to test as the first activity before running the test recorder.

```
    <activity android:name="ActivityToTest">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And after recording the test of that activity I just restore the manifest.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will not be helpful if I am having a lot of activities.

Comment: This is Probably a work around and if we can use it somehow. But in a complex structure this wont be usefull

Answer (score 1):

If your application flow is HomeActivity after Login Activity then you will not be able to launch HomeActvity first